# Is equilibrum condition consequence of second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Equilibrum state is generally stated to be most stable state. Is equilibrium state consequence of second law of thermodynamics at microscopic level. i.e a system tends to reach the equilibrium state as that is the most probable state.?

Thanks,

Comment: [2nd law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics#Second_law) of thermod.: *"When two initially isolated systems in separate but nearby regions of space, each in thermod. equil. with itself but not necessarily with each other, are then allowed to interact, they will eventually reach a mutual **thermod. equil.**. The sum of entropies of the initially isolated systems $\le$ the total entropy of the final combination."*
This statement of the law recognizes that in classical thermod. the entropy of a system is defined only when it has reached its own internal thermod. equilibrium.

Comment: In short, the answer is *yes*.

Comment: Although Sofia's answer is fine, I am not sure what you mean exactly by "state" in your question. It is a bit confusing since you also talk about microscopic level. What idea of state do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: @JánLalinský can't you elaborate a bit? I tried your refs. and I got an *"Oops! explorer could not find ..."*. If you'd explain us a little, it would be helpful. I know that a system of particle at thermod. equilibrium has a well-defined **temperature**. At that temperature, if it is an ideal gas it obeys the Maxwell-Boltzman law of energy distribution, and it also has max. entropy. But, if it is not so, explain us a bit why it isn't so?

Comment: @Sofia, 2nd law of thermodynamics does not address the process of reaching equilibrium state; equilibrium state existence is assumed at the beginning of development of thermodynamics (minus first law). See http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/313/1/engtot.pdf, http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/217/1/Time-asymmetry.pdf

Comment: @Sofia, I've corrected addresses, try the links now (it is a good read).

Answer (score 1):

No, existence of equilibrium state is a separate basic assumption of thermodynamics, necessary to formulate both first and second law. The second law stated in terms of entropy talks *only* about equilibrium states, so they need to be introduced before the 2nd law is derived. More in the papers by Uffink & Brown:

http://hilsci-archive.pitt.edu/313/1/engtot.pdf,
http://hilsci-archive.pitt.edu/217/1/Time-asymmetry.pdf

Comment: In thermal equilibrium, the macrostate with most multiplicities is most probable; though there may be fluctuations. The Fundamental Assumption of Statistical Mechanics is that under thermal equilibrium, all microstates are equally likely which means at __thermal equilibrium__ also, other macrostates may also occur. Am I right?

Comment: In statistical physics, all microstates compatible with  *fixed* macrostate are equally probable. Other macrostates do not enter the consideration. But it is true, from the standpoint of mechanics, that system may spontaneously go from microstate compatible with equilibrium macrostate to a state that is not compatible with any equilibrium macrostate.